Can not retrieve accounts with web3.eth.getaccounts()
I am studying Stephen Grider's course on Ethereum & Solidity.
The code looks like this where I am trying to get some test accounts with ganache.
const assert = require('assert');
const ganache = require('ganache');
const { Web3 } = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider());

beforeEach(() => {
  // Get a list of all accounts
  web3.eth.getAccounts().then((fetchedAccounts) => {
    console.log(fetchedAccounts);
  });
});

describe("Inbox", () => {
  it("deploys a contract", () => {});
});

But when I run this, I am getting this error
Exception during run: Error: Not supported
    at Object.exports.doImport (C:\Users\dipayan\inbox\node_modules\mocha\lib\nodejs\esm-utils.js:35:34)
    at formattedImport (C:\Users\dipayan\inbox\node_modules\mocha\lib\nodejs\esm-utils.js:9:28)
    at Object.exports.requireOrImport (C:\Users\dipayan\inbox\node_modules\mocha\lib\nodejs\esm-utils.js:42:34)
    at Object.exports.loadFilesAsync (C:\Users\dipayan\inbox\node_modules\mocha\lib\nodejs\esm-utils.js:100:34)
    at Mocha.loadFilesAsync (C:\Users\dipayan\inbox\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:449:19)
    at singleRun (C:\Users\dipayan\inbox\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\run-helpers.js:162:15)
    at exports.runMocha (C:\Users\dipayan\inbox\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\run-helpers.js:239:10)
    at Object.exports.handler (C:\Users\dipayan\inbox\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\run.js:375:11)
    at C:\Users\dipayan\inbox\node_modules\yargs\build\index.cjs:443:71
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! inbox@1.0.0 test: `mocha`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the inbox@1.0.0 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\dipayan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2024-08-13T23_59_44_415Z-debug.log

And the error in the debug log looks like this
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'test'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.11.3
3 info using node@v12.11.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'pretest', 'test', 'posttest' ]
5 info lifecycle inbox@1.0.0~pretest: inbox@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle inbox@1.0.0~test: inbox@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle inbox@1.0.0~test: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle inbox@1.0.0~test: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\dipayan\inbox\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk11.0.15_9\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.6\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\SourceGear\Common\DiffMerge\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.9.3-bin\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\Users\dipayan\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap;C:\Users\dipayan\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\heroku\bin;C:\Users\dipayan\sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3390100;C:\Users\dipayan\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin
9 verbose lifecycle inbox@1.0.0~test: CWD: C:\Users\dipayan\inbox
10 silly lifecycle inbox@1.0.0~test: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'mocha' ]
11 silly lifecycle inbox@1.0.0~test: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle inbox@1.0.0~test: Failed to exec test script
13 verbose stack Error: inbox@1.0.0 test: `mocha`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:210:5)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
14 verbose pkgid inbox@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\dipayan\inbox
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19045
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "test"
18 verbose node v12.11.0
19 verbose npm  v6.11.3
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error inbox@1.0.0 test: `mocha`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the inbox@1.0.0 test script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

I tried changing web3 versions, but it does not help. Tried running in admin mode too.
I tried to change the version of mocha too. Apparently this error is coming from a particular line of code in esm.utils.js that is doing import(file) and that is failing.
Here is the snippet
exports.doImport = async file => import(file);

exports.requireOrImport = async (file, esmDecorator) => {
  if (path.extname(file) === '.mjs') {
    return formattedImport(file, esmDecorator);
  }
  try {
    return dealWithExports(await formattedImport(file, esmDecorator));

Any guidance would be helpful pls.

Pls ignore, I got the reason. I was running an older version of node. Upgraded it to latest LTS version and it worked perfectly fine.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
